# pure E4 usage activeWhen Expression

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp, e4, property-testing

I'm migrating my E3 to a pure E4 application. The E3 application used the activeWhen-Core Expression in Combination with propertyTesters to enable/disable ToolItems live. Now in E4 there is only the VisibleWhen Core Expression supported (right?).

Would I do this with the @CanExecute-Annotation now or is there a (hidden) activeWhen Expression? 
And if so, can I use the already existing Testers in this case or would it be better to use a new approach (like and inidividual Test for the individual cases)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no activeWhen expression in e4.

If you define a Handler for a Command in the main Handlers table in the Application.e4xmi then that is active everywhere and you will have to use its `@CanExecute` to control if the ToolItem/MenuItem is enabled.

An alternative is to define a Handler for a Command in the handler table for a Part (or Window). Then the ToolItem/MenuItem will only be active if there is a handler defined for the active part and its `@CanExecute` returns true.

Comment: Thanks for the response! What do you mean by a single Handler? Right now i got multiple Commands and Handlers. Each for each ToolItem. Now I´d like to enable/disable them and i used to do that with the activeWhen expression. You mean to do that now by the @CanExecute ?

Comment: I have expanded the answer.

Comment: Ah I see, so you mean that I could create 2 Handlers for the same Command on 2 Application-Levels, right ?
I already went a little into the CanExecute, what could be a pssoböe reason for why the CanExecute is always executed 4 times in a row ?

Comment: Eclipse is free to run the @CanExecute whenever it wants. You would have to look at the source code to see what it is doing for each call.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it is free to run". Isn´t there a rule ?
E.g. Lars Vogels Book says, that if connected to a ToolBarItem, it should be runned every 400ms, but in my case it isn´t

Comment: I mean whenever the Eclipse developers think they need it to run. If I remember correctly the 400ms was dropped some time ago as it caused too much load. When nothing is happening the @CanExecute is not called at all.

Comment: Note: The **Third** edition of Lars's book (now called 'Eclipse Rich Client Platform') drops the mention of 400ms.